# Error in React/Redux - Expected an assignment or function call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Couldn't find a past answer that helped.
I try using a Redux reducer, and I get this error message :

```
Line 30:15:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused- 
expressions
```

The reducer :

```
  const chatsReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
      let sender = action.sender;
      let message = action.message;

      let newMessage = {
        sender: sender,
        message: message
      };

      switch (action.type) {
        case SEND_MESSAGE:
          let newMessage = {
            sender: sender,
            message: message
          }

          let newState = {...state, chats: state.chats.push(newMessage)}
          return state


        default:
          state;
      }
      return state;
    };
```

Line 30 that's in the error is where I return the state as default.
Any idea what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're creating a variable called newState and then not using it because you return state

```
let newState = {...state, chats: state.chats.push(newMessage)} // not used
      return state // return state
```

Comment: Changed it and problem persists

Comment: there are only 25 lines in this method. You're also not return anything in the default, but changing it probably won't fix your error. Also, why are you returning state outside your switch/case? There's not really enough info here to troubleshoot your problem. You might have more luck with this if you post it on [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: You've got two declarations of newMessage. Get rid of the second one.

Comment: I found the issue. The error stopped appearing after i fixed the "default" line to 
     default:
      return state;
I was missing the "return". Thank u for your help anyways.